# Copy only certain pages from word doc into excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, ms-word

1) I open a pdf using Microsoft word, through excel VBA.

2) From the word doc, I wish to copy only page 3 and page 4 (these two are tables without captions) into excel

3) at the moment, I could only copy the entire word doc into the excel, which can be troublesome.

below is my code:

```
Sub convertpdftowordthenexcel()

Dim wordapp As Word.Application
Dim input1 As String
input1 = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Fruitjuice.pdf"

'open pdf in word
Set wordapp = New Word.Application

wordapp.documents.Open Filename:=input1, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False
wordapp.Visible = True
'copy the content of the word file
wordapp.ActiveDocument.Content.Copy     '<------this is where I want to change

'go to excel and paste it there
Workbooks("openpdfusingdoc.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text"

wordapp.Quit savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

End Sub
```

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks so much guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access tables through the tables collection - you may need to workout what index number the two you want are, I've assumed they're the first two in the document

```
 Sub convertpdftowordthenexcel()

 Dim wordapp As Word.Application
 Dim input1 As String
 input1 = "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\Fruitjuice.pdf"

 'open pdf in word
 Set wordapp = New Word.Application

 wordapp.documents.Open Filename:=input1, Format:="PDF Files", ConfirmConversions:=False
 wordapp.Visible = True
'copy the first two tables of the word file
 wordapp.ActiveDocument.tables(1).range.Copy     

 'go to excel and paste it there
 with Workbooks("openpdfusingdoc.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
     .Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Format:="Text"
     wordapp.ActiveDocument.tables(2).range.Copy    
    .cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).offset(2,0).pastespecial format:="Text"
  end with
  wordapp.Quit savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

 End Sub
```

(PS Never use Select)

Comment: thanks. worked like a charm. However the table index starts with 2 instead of 1. So I guess the creator of the document inserted a table somewhere in the doc as the 1st table. One question though, why never use select? I've been using VBA for a while and I've seen this advice before but no one ever explain why should we avoid using select

Comment: Consider r=3 (where r is an object variable of type range pointing to "A1") with Range("a1").Select:Activecell.formula = 3
The latter requires twice as many lines, but a vastly increased number of processes. The first version PUTS the value 3 into the memory location pointed to by r - this takes 1 clock cycle. The second requires that excel check to see if the cell is visible, if not scroll the screen to bring it into view, check to see if the formula bar is visible, if so set it to the details of the new cell, check if the display bar is displayed, if so,...

Comment: ...lookup which auto-updating formulas are displayed and update them, and finally redraw the screen. 
Then for the second line, look up what is the activecell, look up where in memory it is, PUT 3 into that cell, look up what number format is applied to the cell, calculate how the number will display in that format, and finally redraw the screen.