# I need a starting point to code an app to extract text from pdf to excel

Tags: python, django, excel, pdf

To start I just want to state that I'm an Electrical Engineer with basic knowledge of programming.

My requirement is as follows:

- I want to create an app where I can load and view PDF files that
  contain tables.
- These PDF files tables are of irregular shapes and in a different
  position on every page. (that's why tools like tabular couldn't help
  me)
- Each table entry is multiline and of irregular dimensions (I cannot
  select a whole row at a time it has to be each element alone. simply
  copying the lines to excel won't work either because it will need a
  lot of formatting)
- So I want to be able to select each table entry individually from the
  table (like a selection or cropping box over the required text),
  delete new line if there is a new line in the text and just keep spaces.
- The generated excel (or access database I do not really mind any)
  should be reviewable and saveable (if those are even words XD).

I have a good knowledge of python and a very elementary knowledge of Django and I'm seeking some expert who can tell me what do I really need to learn (and if possible where to learn it) to execute my project.

Is it very much for me to execute and if I can dedicate 10 hours a week, how much would it take me to execute such a project.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Python, use Word. Open the pdf, then step through the tables collection to collect the data and put it into excel. See this [for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55273025/copy-only-certain-pages-from-word-doc-into-excel-using-vba/55279280#55279280)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the advises I can provide you :
first of all, ask internet for questions :  
https://lmddgtfy.net/?q=python%20library%20tabular%20pdf 
-> Camelot , which is mentioned multiple time seems to be relevant

For the use of **excel** sheet, i present you one of the most famous library for manipulating DataFrame: Pandas
You can use small courses on internet which will offer you a quick ability to manage your project easier.

for the **application**, you can easily find on **youtube courses** on a library made by someone who will explain you how to do a basic application. It could offer you the entry point you are talking about. Then, You can just wonder what else do you need or simply want for making it better.

for the time needed, it depends on how much time do you need to understand the basics, how much time you spend on having a deeper comprehension. I think in one week, working during your free time with a real interest, it could be working( not perfect, but working, which is a good beginning)